# Android JSON Parser

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse the JSON located at http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/Default?offset=0&limit=1.

```java
{
"total": 15000,
"entries": [
    {
        "online": false,
        "rank": 1,
        "character": {
            "name": "Byrr",
            "level": 85,
            "class": "Shadow",
            "experience": 1397076236
        },
        "account": {
            "name": "Canoobians"
        }
    }
]
}
```

I've been following the [androidhive tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) while attempting to modify it to retrive the "online" and "rank" elements. (Eventually I want all of the elements with large numbers of entries, but I'm starting with just those two to try to understand things.

```java
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// url to make request
private static String url = "http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/Default?offset=0&limit=2";

// JSON node names
private static final String TAG_ENTRIES = "entries";
private static final String TAG_ONLINE = "online";
private static final String TAG_RANK = "rank";

// entries JSONArray
JSONArray entries = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> entriesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // create JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from url
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of entries
        entries = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ENTRIES);

        // looping through entries
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject ent = entries.getJSONObject(i);

            // storing each JSON item in a variable
            String online = ent.getString(TAG_ONLINE);
            String rank = ent.getString(TAG_RANK);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ONLINE, online);
            map.put(TAG_RANK, rank);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            entriesList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, entriesList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ONLINE, TAG_RANK }, new int[] { R.id.online, R.id.rank });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

My JSONParser() class is the same as in the tutorial. Now when I run the program I get the error:

```java
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.
```

I don't know why this error is happening since the JSON is valid according to JSONLint, so it shouldn't be sending any HTML, correct? Is there something I'm missing, or even a completely different/better way to extract the JSON? Any kicks in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT :** I can't self answer yet since I'm a new user, but It turns out that I was getting a `NullPointerException` in `JSONParser()` that I didn't see before, and using `HttpGet()` rather than `HttpPost()` solved my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm all for learning to write your parsers, but have checked to see if some existing JSON parsers are fit for the job? My favorite has always been GSON and has served me well in my Android projects. It's at least one less thing for you to maintain.

Comment: Maybe you should indicate what line you're getting the error on??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was getting a `NullPointerException` in `JSONParser()` that I didn't see before and using `HttpGet()` rather than `HttpPost()` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line in JSONParser

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
```

Site returns this header

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

You have to change iso-8859-1 to UTF-8 in  BufferedReader.

Comment: Thanks, but the androidhive site is using UTF-8, not the JSON I'm trying to parse, which is iso-8859-1. Changing it did cause me to notice a NullPointerException that I didn't see before. Changing the HttpPost to HttpGet in JSONParser fixed everything, but I'm not entirely sure why that is.